# Unable to substitute 0 with L and 1 with H in a Perl string

Tags: perl, replace, binary, hex, substring

I am grappling with just a simple piece of code and unable to troubleshoot my way through. All I am trying to do is substitute 0 with L and 1 with H for the binary equivalent of a hex number. I need to get the hex number from the user, convert it to binary, scan through each bit of the binary and replace 0's with L's and 1's with H's. Simple requirement yet finding it hard to resolve.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $i2c = "80";
my $binary_string = sprintf "%08b", hex($i2c);
print "$binary_string \n";

my $charz = sprintf "%s", $binary_string;
print "$charz\n";

for (my $i=1; $i < @charz; $i++) {
  if (substr($charz, $i) eq "0")
    substr($charz, $i) = "L";
  else if (substr($charz, $i) eq "1")
    substr($charz, $i) = "H";
}
```

My output should be like this:

```
input hex = 80
```

Therefore binary will be `10000000`.
So my output has to be `HLLLLLLL`.

I am not able to get this simple output. I tried a wide range of things to make it work (regex match and replace substring, index etc). I am not sure if I am making a basic error somewhere. Kindly help me out on this one.

The error that I get is this:

```
syntax error at temp3.pl line 12, near ")
substr"
Execution of temp3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: I'd advise looking at the s// construct: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html

Comment: You might as well skip this line `my $charz = sprintf "%s", $binary_string;` since it does nothing at all, except create a new copy of your string.

Comment: Yes I tried s// but I guess the problem must have been with the braces thing as mentioned below. I must have gotten thrown off from what was actually incorrect in the code.

Comment: yes I agree.. I am taking that off..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl `if` statements always require `{` and `}` around the action:

```
if (substr($charz, $i) eq "0")
{
    substr($charz, $i) = "L";
}
else if (substr($charz, $i) eq "1")
{
    substr($charz, $i) = "H";
}
```

(You should probably look at the enclosing loop indexes too; arrays index from 0 in Perl unless you really like to live dangerously.  And, while we're deconstructing the code, as [TLP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725418/tlp) commented, the assignment to `$charz` via `sprintf` is a long-winded way of writing `$charz = $binary_string;`!)

Also, as [hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500553/perl-unable-to-subsitute-0-with-l-and-1-with-h-in-a-string#comment37929542_24500579), the `substr()` operator needs a third argument to work as you want it to:

```
if (substr($charz, $i, 1) eq "0")
{
    substr($charz, $i, 1) = "L";
}
else if (substr($charz, $i, 1) eq "1")
{
    substr($charz, $i, 1) = "H";
}
```

Or you could use:

```
substr($charz, $i, 1) = "L" if (substr($charz, $i, 1) eq "0");
substr($charz, $i, 1) = "H" if (substr($charz, $i, 1) eq "1");
```

Or you could avoid the explicit loop and use:

```
$charz =~ s/1/H/g;
$charz =~ s/0/L/g;
```

Or you could use:

```
$charz =~ y/01/LH/;
```

Or you could spell `y` as `tr`:

```
$charz =~ tr/01/LH/;
```

Or all the other ways you can do it in Perl...

Of the mechanisms shown, I'd use `y` or `tr` (probably `tr` is preferred; `y` is for die-hard `sed` programmers); it does it all in one line: no fuss, no muss.

Comment: The `LENGTH` argument to `substr` defaults to "the rest of the string". If you want the `substr` version to work, you should give it a third argument of 1. However, I recommend the `y` version (or rather `tr`) because that's exactly what that operator is for :)

Comment: @hobbs: thanks for the reminder about `substr()` -- I seldom use it so I'd forgotten that wrinkle.

Comment: I guess I am overwhelmed. Thank you for the consolidated response. I am enlightened today with the many possibilities of how this could be done. I think I am going to use tr. Looks nice and clean.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $i2c = "80";

my $binary_string = sprintf "%08b", hex($i2c);
print "$binary_string \n";

$binary_string =~ tr/10/HL/;
print "$binary_string\n";
```

Outputs:

```
10000000
HLLLLLLL
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice and clean method. I never knew about tr before.

Answer (score 2):

Using `tr//` is probably the best solution, as has been noted. I just wanted to add this bitwise comparison method, since you are using bits, and its fun:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $bin = shift // 0x80;                 # take arg or default
my $str;
for (my $n = 1; $n <= $bin; $n *= 2) {   # $n -> 1, 2, 4, ...
    $str .= $bin & $n ? 'H' : 'L';       # check bits
}
$str = reverse $str;                     # well...
printf "Org: %b\nNew: $str\n", $bin;
```

**Some test runs:**

```
$ foo.pl
Org: 10000000
New: HLLLLLLL

$ foo.pl 3
Org: 11
New: HH

$ foo.pl 31
Org: 11111
New: HHHHH

$ foo.pl 33
Org: 100001
New: HLLLLH
```

Comment: Wonderful bit manipulation. But I wonder how you conceived this. Hats off. Just a  quick question though. Just curious. Internally are the operands on either side of bitwise AND converted to binary before being ANDed bitwise? So I am assuming we don't need to sprintf "%0b" etc to the $bin and $str variables for ANDing correct?

Comment: Perl will indeed convert arguments if necessary, depending on what type is required by the operator. E.g. with `eq` the arguments are converted to strings, with `==` they are converted to numbers. As for numbers, Perl does not retain their representation, e.g. `0x90`, that is only done if you store them as strings, `"0x90"`. So in a nutshell, no, you don't need to worry about how your number is represented.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regexp:

```
$charz =~ s/0/L/g;
$charz =~ s/1/H/g;
```

Comment: Thank you Geeky. I had also tried the =~ s/find text/replace text, but the lack of braces around the if condition must have been the culprit I guess. Thanks and the regex find and replace method works. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Running your code as given, I get the error 'Global symbol "@charz" requires explicit package name at string line 11'.

And that's true, because you're using the array @charz (in your `for` loop condition) without defining it anywhere. The fact that you don't mention this error in your question makes me think that you're not showing us the code that you're actually running. At the very least, you don't have `use strict` turned on in your real code.

If I comment out the `use strict` line, I get the syntax error that you mentioned. That's caused by the missing braces that other people have pointed out. We can also tidy things up a bit by using `elsif` in place of `else if`.

```
for (my $i=1; $i < @charz; $i++) {
  if (substr($charz, $i) eq "0") {
    substr($charz, $i) = "L";
  } elsif (substr($charz, $i) eq "1") {
    substr($charz, $i) = "H";
  }
}
```

Now we get to a situation where the code runs, but nothing changes. That's because of that `$i < @charz`. The array is empty, so your loop doesn't run and nothing changes.

We can fix that by changing the foreach loop to this:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < length$charz; $i++) {
  ...
}
```

But that **still** doesn't work because of the `substr` issues that others have mentioned.

So what you were actually trying to write (I think) was this:

```
for (my $i=0; $i < length$charz; $i++) {
  if (substr($charz, $i, 1) eq "0") {
    substr($charz, $i, 1) = "L";
  } elsif (substr($charz, $i, 1) eq "1") {
    substr($charz, $i, 1) = "H";
  }
}
```

This works as expected. But you're doing far too much work here. You should have used `tr///` :-)

Comment: Dave, you are absolutely right. I actually was manually typing the code so it did not turn out to be exactly off from the script. Thank you for pointing out the errors. I have moved to using tr now for this type of requirement. I would like to vote up your answer and some of the other answers here too, but am unable to do so as I do not have enough reputation points to do so as I am new to stackoverflow. However, I could only check mark on the most helpful answer and I have chosen Jonathan Leffler's answer as the model answer as it consolidates the different ways that this could be done.